# Docker error does not allow me to deploy my app

Tags: docker

Im trying to deploy my docker app but i keep running into an error

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNS2C.png)

Comment: Can you share compose yaml?

Comment: You're not in the same directory as docker-compose. Change directory to docker-compose's directory and try to re-run it, or give fullpath to docker-compose file.

Comment: thx it worked thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd docker and then Re-run your command
```